# IDA Portable executable pe

Tags: portable-executable, ida

In my loader section missing PE, how to fix it?

[image: Missing PE]

Only two options dos.ldw and Binary file.

Have nice day.

Comment: Try testing with a known good executable.  If that doesn't work, maybe your copy of IDA is broken.  If it does work, the binary file you are trying to run through has no PE header.  If there is no PE header, IDA won't be able to tell what type of binary file it is supposed to be, which is why it is asking you.  Do you know if the file contains 32-bit code?  Do you know which architecture?  If it is data, you probably want to use a hex editor.

Comment: @bytepointer: By the looks of things, it doesn't even have an MZ header: IDA is only offering to load it as COM or straight binary